# Forcing MSVC to generate FIST instructions with the /QIfist option

Tags: visual-c++, x86, intel, fpu

I'm using the [`/QIfist` compiler switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6d9xx1d2.aspx) regularly, which causes the compiler to generate `FISTP` instructions to round floating point values to integers, instead of calling the `_ftol` helper function.

How can I make it use `FIST(P) DWORD`, instead of `QWORD`?

`FIST QWORD` requires the CPU to store the result on stack, then read stack into register and finally store to destination memory, while `FIST DWORD` just stores directly into destination memory.

Comment: The options are covered well in Agner Fog's [optimizing_cpp.pdf](http://www.agner.org/optimize/) document, chapter 14.8

Comment: So it looks like it is not possible to make QIfist use DWORD.

Answer (score 0):

> FIST QWORD requires the CPU to store the result on stack, then read stack into register and finally store to destination memory, while FIST DWORD just stores directly into destination memory.

I don't understand what you are trying to say here.
The `FIST` and `FISTP` instructions differ from each other in exactly two ways:

1. **`FISTP` *pops* the top value off of the floating point stack**, while `FIST` does not. This is the obvious difference, and is reflected in the opcode naming: `FISTP` has that `P` suffix, which means "pop", just like `ADDP`, etc.
2. **`FISTP`** has an additional encoding that **works with 64-bit (`QWORD`) operands**. That means you can use `FISTP` to convert a floating point value to a 64-bit integer. `FIST`, on the other hand, maxes out at 32-bit (`DWORD`) operands.

   <sup>(I don't think there's a technical reason for this. I certainly can't imagine it is related to the popping behavior. I assume that when the Intel engineers added support for 64-bit operands some time later, they figured there was no reason for a non-popping version. They were probably running out of opcode encodings.)</sup>

There are lots of online references for the x86 instruction set. For example, [this site](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_98.html) is the top hit for most Google searches. Or you can look in [Intel's manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf) (`FIST`/`FISTP` are on p. 365).

**Where the two instructions *read* the value from, and where they *store* it to, is exactly the same. Both read the value from the top of the floating point stack, and both store the result to memory.**

There would be absolutely no advantage to the compiler using `FIST` instead of `FISTP`. Remember that you *always* have to pop all values off of the floating point stack when exiting from a function, so if `FIST` is used, you'd have to follow it by an additional `FSTP` instruction. That might not be any slower, but it would needlessly inflate the code.

Besides, there's another reason that the compiler prefers `FISTP`: the support for 64-bit operands. It allows the code generator to be identical, regardless of what size integer you're rounding to.

The *only* time you might prefer to use `FIST` is if you're hand-writing assembly code and want to re-use the floating point value on the stack *after* rounding it. The compiler doesn't need to do that.

So anyway, all of that to say that the answer to your question is no. The compiler can't be made to generate `FIST` instructions automatically. If you're still insistent, you can write inline assembly that uses whatever instructions you want:

```
int32 RoundToNearestEven(float value)
{
    int32 result;
    __asm
    {
        fld   DWORD PTR value
        fist  DWORD PTR result
        // do something with the value on the floating point stack...
        // 
        // ... but be sure to pop it off before returning
        fstp  st(0)
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You have changed the title of my question, completely changing the meaning. I do not care at all if the compiler will use `FIST` or `FISTP`, I only wanted to make it use `DWORD` instead of `QWORD`. The compiler uses 64 bits and generates this code: `FISTP QWORD PTR [esp+xx]: MOV EAX,[ESP+xx]: MOV [DEST],EAX`, and it could use 32 bits and generate a single `FISTP [DEST]`. Since I know the number will fit in 32 bits, I see no reason for the compiler to use 64 bit version.

Comment: Hmm. The question didn't make much sense to me, so I answered it as best I could. I thought my interpretation was correct, so I tried to clarify the question for others. It hadn't yet received an answer. I assumed that's because others didn't understand it either. Sorry about that, feel free to modify it however you like.